# How to serve static files from root path '/'

Tags: node.js, express

I understand that Express needs to be told where to serve static files from using something like `server.use(express.static('public');` if all your static files reside in the `public` folder.

However there are static files in my app which MUST be served from the root of the site e.g.

- http://example.com/ads.txt
- http://example.com/sitemap.xml
- http://example.com/app.webmanifest

I cannot create a separate route for each static file in the root folder because there can be many. When they are bundled up into the `dist` folder for deployment, they reside in the root of the site alongside the `package.json` file etc.

How can it be possible to serve the app's homepage at the route of `'/'` and also static files from that same route? e.g.:

```
server.use('/', express.static('/client')); 

server.get('/', async (req, res) => {
// serve homepage here
})
```

Comment: The `public` you pass to `express.static` has nothing to do with the HTTP route express serves it from.

Comment: @tkausl can you explain more with an example? i don't understand

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = express()


app.use(express.static('folder_name'))
```

Or

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/folder_mame'));
app.set('folder_name', __dirname);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to official docs:
***Serving static files in Express***
To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express.

The function signature is:

express.static(root, [options])
The root argument specifies the root directory from which to serve static assets. For more information on the options argument, see [express static](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static).

For example, use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory named public:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Now, you can load the files that are in the public directory:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css
http://localhost:3000/js/app.js
http://localhost:3000/images/bg.png
http://localhost:3000/hello.html
```

[Serving static files Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: My static files don't reside in a `public` folder. They are in the root folder.

Comment: @volumeone then put them in `public` ^^